# Turbo Frame in Rails 7, why is the page specified in the SRC not loading?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-7, hotwire-rails, turbo, turbo-frames

I am writing a rails app and making use of turbo frame.  I have done a very similar thing in a previous app and didn't have this same problem.

All the content that changes is in a turbo frame called content, so that the sidebar and header are not touched whenever the page changes.
Within this I have two further turbo frames, that I wanted to give SRC attributes so that something loads when the pages is first visited but can then be replaced as the user filters a table. For some reason these pages never load.

Looking at the terminal there doesn't seem to be any call to the server, and if I visit the path generated in the html element separately it seems to work so no idea why it is not being called. I assume it's something to do with the frames being nested but as I said I have done this before with no issues.

If I add a loading animation into the frame that works, but is never replaced as it should be by the src path.

My 'specs/index.html.erb' file

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag :content do %>

  <div class="content_window">

    <%= button_to new_style_path, :method => :get do %>
      <i class="icon">add</i>&nbsp;New Style
    <% end %> <!-- new style button --> 

    <%= turbo_frame_tag :spec do %>
      <h1>Latest Spec <%= @specs.first.name %></h2>
    <% end %> <!-- spec turbo frame -->

    <%= turbo_frame_tag :spec_table, src: spec_table_path do %>
      <div class="single4"></div>
    <% end %>

  </div> <!-- content_window -->  

<% end %> <!-- content turbo frame -->
```

My 'specs/spec_table.html.erb' file

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag :spec_table do %>
  <table class="spec_list">
    <tr>
      <th>Style Number</th>
      <th>Style Name</th>
      <th>Created on</th>
    </tr>
    <% @specs.each do |spec| %>
        <tr onclick="location.href='<%= style_path(spec.id) %>'">
          <td><%= spec.style_num %></td>
          <td><%= spec.name %></td>
          <td><%= spec.created_at %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
      
  </table>
<% end %>
```

Spec Controller

```
class SpecsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_spec, only: %i[show]

  def index
    @specs = Style.all.sort_by(&:style_num)
  end

  def show
  end

  def spec_table
    @specs = Style.all.sort_by(&:style_num)
  end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "specs/index", to: "specs#index", as: "specs"
  get "specs/spec_table", to: "specs#spec_table", as: "spec_table"
  get "specs/:id", to: "specs#show", as: "spec"
  get "pages/dash", to: "pages#dash", as: "dash"
  

  resources :styles
  devise_for :users
  devise_scope :user do
    match '/sessions/user', to: 'devise/sessions#create', via: :post
  end

  get 'pages/index'
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
   root "pages#index"
end
```

I see there is a similar question previously which mentions JS bundling, which I don't know anything about.  Import maps has seemingly served me fine, and as I said this has worked on another app I am working on, so assume that's not the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Ignore this, I hadn't installed turbo

Comment: If you think that this question won't be useful for future users, then it would be better to delete the question.